# How to fix irregular cross section and shape-stretching while curving a mesh?

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms

I am trying to create a finger ring made of connected hexagons. The steps I followed were:
1. Create a mesh of 7 connected hexagons lying side to side
2. Bend that mesh using simple deform around a central point
3. Convert that mesh into a curve
4. Use another bezier circle curve as the bevel object to create a cross section for the hexagon curve
5. Convert the hexagon curve into a mesh again

There are 2 issues I am facing here:
1. My hitherto, regular, equal length-sided hexagons have now got stretched after the simple deform modifier, so 4 sides are much longer than the 2 sides
2. The cross section of the mesh is not uniformly circular (and looks a bit twisted)
3. The mesh at the junctions is protruding

Is there a relatively easy way to fix this or should I consider a completely different approach? If the latter, would be great if you can explain the new approach. I have lost a fair amount of hair in trying to figure this out so would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Ayan

[image]

Comment: you have to add more count of hexagons in your array modifier, to avoid stretching in the deform modifier. and also the hexagon cilinders seem not be joined (not after array i mean the original shape of the hexagon , not several hexagons joining)

Comment: are the first and the last hexagons suppose to stick to each other or is it an open shape like in your screenshot?

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid Silly of me - I didn't actually use the array modifier but just copy pasted the base hexagon multiple times. And the base hexagon was just a circle with 6 sides - the sides did not have any cross section to start with. It was only after I had curved the 7 hexagons that I changed the mesh to a curve and then used the curve bevel object to create a cross section using a bezier circle.

Comment: @moonboots It's supposed to be open to allow the wearer to adjust the ring per their finger size

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

- Create a torus with 6 *Major Segments*. Rotate it 90° on the X axis and 30° on the Y axis. Apply the rotation with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.
- Duplicate it and keep a half somewhere.
- Cut the 2 extremities with the knife (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut perpendicularly), separate in the middle with <kbd>V</kbd>, move one half and create an X.
- Give your shape an *Array* modifier with a *Count* of 7, activate the *Merge* and *First Last* options.
- Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode, with the angle you want, for example 280° if your final shape is not closed.
- As you will want to smooth it with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, add some edge loops to your mesh to sharp the edges.
- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, smooth it.
- Keep a copy of your object somewhere. Apply the *Array* and *Simple Deform* modifiers on the original.
- Bring back the half torus you've created at the beginning and stick it to each extremity of the shape with the help of the *Snap* option / *Vertex* mode and *Automatically Merge Vertices* option.
- Go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.

[image]

Comment: I am a bit speechless. At the max I was hoping for some guidance/tips  on how to solve this. For you to take time out on a Sunday to solve the issue with detailed steps and screenshots is a bit mindblowing. Thanks a ton! This looks perfect. I'll try and replicate the steps and let you know in case I get stuck anywhere. You made my Sunday :D

Comment: you're welcome  ;)   I hope it's clear

Comment: Yup - it worked! Thanks again!